# How to show time depend on timezone in java 8 and spring 4?

Tags: java, timezone, java-8, datetime-format, spring-4

I'm working on site that is writing on java 8 and spring 4, we are using java 8 standard time api, now on pages always is shown server time (in user profile is shown date of his registration). With old java time api there was way use  SimpleDateFormat, but it doesn't fit now. Is there a way to convert server time to client time in jsp pages or in controllers?

Answer (score 2):

One of the way to handle this is get users timezone String ( GMT , IST etc ) in request ( using **AJAX or other relevant technology.** )

Now by using new Java 8 Local date API we can achieve this as following:

**Step 1 :** Get Zone from giving zone query parameter that we got from ajax Using Java 8 **ZoneId** class. :

```
ZoneId losAngeles =  ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
```

**Step 2:** Get current time based on that timezone using **LocalTime** API like below:

```
ZoneId losAngeles =  ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"); 
LocalDateTime currentTimeInLosAngeles =  LocalTime.now(losAngeles );
```

**Step 3 :** Get DATETIME of particular zone By Using Java 8 **ZonedDateTime** class

```
 ZoneId losAngeles =  ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"); 
 LocalDateTime currentTimeInLosAngeles =  LocalTime.now(losAngeles );
 ZonedDateTime losAngelsDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(currentTimeInLosAngeles , losAngeles );
```